# asp:CheckBoxList renders as span and no checkboxes(FF and webkit)

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, firefox, checkboxlist, html-rendering

I am using CheckboxList control of the asp.net. it was working fine as expected in past but certainly it started not rendering properly in chrome and firefox browsers. It renders perfectly in Internet Explorer (9 in my case).

It renders in span tag like following

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <span id="cntMain_chkColumns">Activity IDActivity TItleSubmitted ByActivity DateRequest DateAmountStatusExternal Activity IDCustomer ID</span>
</div>
```

[image]

While the correct and expected rendering (From IE) is as follows

```
<span class="defaultP checkbox-wp drag-box-wp  ui-draggable ui-droppable makeDragDrop"><div class="ez-checkbox ez-checked"><input id="cntMain_chkColumns_0" class="ez-hide" name="ctl00$cntMain$chkColumns$0" value="0" CHECKED="checked" type="checkbox"></div><label for="cntMain_chkColumns_0">Activity ID</label></span>
<span
class="defaultP checkbox-wp drag-box-wp  ui-draggable ui-droppable makeDragDrop">
  <div class="ez-checkbox ez-checked">
    <input id="cntMain_chkColumns_1" class="ez-hide" name="ctl00$cntMain$chkColumns$1" value="1" CHECKED="checked" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <label for="cntMain_chkColumns_1">Activity TItle</label>
  </span><span class="defaultP checkbox-wp drag-box-wp  ui-draggable ui-droppable makeDragDrop"><div class="ez-checkbox ez-checked"><input id="cntMain_chkColumns_2" class="ez-hide" name="ctl00$cntMain$chkColumns$2" value="2" CHECKED="checked" type="checkbox"></div><label for="cntMain_chkColumns_2">Submitted By</label></span>
  <span
  class="defaultP checkbox-wp drag-box-wp  ui-draggable ui-droppable makeDragDrop">
    <div class="ez-checkbox ez-checked">
      <input id="cntMain_chkColumns_3" class="ez-hide" name="ctl00$cntMain$chkColumns$3" value="3" CHECKED="checked" type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <label for="cntMain_chkColumns_3">Activity Date</label>
    </span><span class="defaultP checkbox-wp drag-box-wp  ui-draggable ui-droppable makeDragDrop"><div class="ez-checkbox ez-checked"><input id="cntMain_chkColumns_4" class="ez-hide" name="ctl00$cntMain$chkColumns$4" value="4" CHECKED="checked" type="checkbox"></div><label for="cntMain_chkColumns_4">Request Date</label></span>
    <br><span class="defaultP checkbox-wp drag-box-wp  ui-draggable ui-droppable makeDragDrop"><div class="ez-checkbox ez-checked"><input id="cntMain_chkColumns_5" class="ez-hide" name="ctl00$cntMain$chkColumns$5" value="5" CHECKED="checked" type="checkbox"></div><label for="cntMain_chkColumns_5">Amount</label></span>
    <span
    class="defaultP checkbox-wp drag-box-wp  ui-draggable ui-droppable makeDragDrop">
      <div class="ez-checkbox ez-checked">
        <input id="cntMain_chkColumns_6" class="ez-hide" name="ctl00$cntMain$chkColumns$6" value="6" CHECKED="checked" type="checkbox">
      </div>
      <label for="cntMain_chkColumns_6">Status</label>
      </span><span class="defaultP checkbox-wp drag-box-wp  ui-draggable ui-droppable makeDragDrop"><div class="ez-checkbox ez-checked"><input id="cntMain_chkColumns_7" class="ez-hide" name="ctl00$cntMain$chkColumns$7" value="7" CHECKED="checked" type="checkbox"></div><label for="cntMain_chkColumns_7">External Activity ID</label></span>
      <span
      class="defaultP checkbox-wp drag-box-wp  ui-draggable ui-droppable makeDragDrop">
        <div class="ez-checkbox ez-checked">
          <input id="cntMain_chkColumns_8" class="ez-hide" name="ctl00$cntMain$chkColumns$8" value="8" CHECKED="checked" type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <label for="cntMain_chkColumns_8">Customer ID</label>
        </span>
        <br>
```

[image]

**CSS **
Below are the css rules which are supposed to be applied if checkbox renders :(

```
.defaultP - is a dummy class for calling ezMark plugin.
.drag-box-wp{ border:1px dashed #cccccc; padding:7px; display:inline; float:left; width:100%; margin:0 0 20px 20px; background:#ffffff; max-width: 195px; }
```

Remaining are the classes for jquery-ui-draggable interaction widget.

Below is my markup

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkColumns" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatLayout="Flow"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I bind this checkbox list on click of a button the binding code in c# code-behind file goes like below

```
 DataView dvCustomizableColumns = dtCustomizableColumns.DefaultView;
 dvCustomizableColumns.Sort = "Sequence_ID ASC";
 chkColumns.DataSource = dvCustomizableColumns;
 chkColumns.DataTextField = "ColumnDisplayName";
 chkColumns.DataValueField = "Sequence_ID";
 chkColumns.DataBind();
```

Later using a function i make these checkboxes draggable and apply some styling on check boxes using [ezMark Plugin](https://github.com/itsalif/ezMark).

Code :

```
    private void EnableDraggingOnItems(DataView dvCustomizableColumns)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < dvCustomizableColumns.Table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
         if (hdnSelectedColumns.Value != string.Empty)
          {
           if (hdnSelectedColumns.Value.Contains(chkColumns.Items[i].Value))
            {
              chkColumns.Items[i].Selected = true;
            }
          }
         else
          {
            chkColumns.Items[i].Selected = true;
          }


chkColumns.Items[i].Attributes.Add("class", "defaultP checkbox-wp drag-box-wp  ui-draggable ui-droppable makeDragDrop");
        }
    }
```

i also checked if there is a checkbox webkit style set to none for chrome but it is nowhere in the css.

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Have you tried to use `<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="anything" class="your css class">` ?

Comment: @KevinMaxwell i need to show this multiple checkboxes which are bound to database table or datatable in c#. It used to work but i can not figure out what changes break these. I can use checkboxes as well but that need me to use repeater kind of control and some complex binding and pre selection logic

Comment: Have you tried to use those checkboxes without the ezMark plugin?

Comment: @KevinMaxwell it is not making any difference to what i have with ezMark. The problem is markup should render like the one which i have posted for IE browser but it is not rendering any input checkboxes at all .

Comment: Have you tried to see if there is any error in DOM (F12 - Developer tools) in chrome?

Comment: unfortunately i have no error or clue, neither in firefox nor chrome consoles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89269/discussion-between-kevin-maxwell-and-devjosh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all, who shown interest in my problem. Fortunately i found solution to my question.
It turns out that in my master page, there was a jquery starts with selector causing the innerHtml of the checkbox list to be altered.

```
$("span[id^='cntMain']").each(function () {
                $(this).text($(this).text().toString().toTitleCase());
            });
```

That's why it renders the labels only.
I changed the selector in above code like following

```
 $("span[id^='cntMain']:not(:has(*))").each(function () {
                $(this).text($(this).text().toString().toTitleCase());
            });
```

Though this is very specific problem i posted the answer in case someone still find it useful.

I am still wondering why and how it worked in IE.